# Why python code with list comprehension take less time than the one without?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I wrote following code:

```
def meth3(history_list, fromDate, toDate):
    active = {}
    chart_data =  [0] * (daysDiff + 1)
    activityData = [(_activityData.user_id, timezone.localtime(_activityData.last_save_time).date()) 
                        for item in history_list for _activityData in item.user.activeData
                    ]
    for iActivityData in activityData:
        if ((iActivityData[0], iActivityData[1]) not in active
            and fromDate < iActivityData[1] and iActivityData[1] < toDate):
            chart_data[(iActivityData[1]-fromDate).days] += 1 
            active[(iActivityData[0], iActivityData[1])] = None
    return chart_data
```

This function runs in max 1.8s consistently. Note that it iterates through the elements twice:

1. in list comprehension to create `activityData` array
2. in `for` loop

So to make it faster, I done away with explicitly creating `activityData` array, thus requiring only single iteration:

```
def meth4(history_list, fromDate, toDate):
    active = {}
    chart_data =  [0] * (daysDiff + 1)
    for history_i in history_list:
        for activityData_i in history_i.user.activeData:
            userId = activityData_i.user_id
            recordLastsaveTime = timezone.localtime(activityData_i.last_save_time).date()
             if ((userId, recordLastsaveTime) not in active 
                and fromDate < recordLastsaveTime and recordLastsaveTime < toDate):
                chart_data[(recordLastsaveTime-fromDate).days] += 1 
                active[(userId, recordLastsaveTime)] = None
    return chart_data
```

But this function takes 2.4+ seconds consistently. Why is this version taking more time than the earlier despite requiring only single iteration?

Comment: You're not going through the data twice.  Your list comprehension creates a SUBSET, so your second loop is making fewer iterations.

Comment: Its not subset or I should say "row subset", but "column subset". I mean I can see that list comprehension gets rid of a lot of fields `item.user` and `item.user.activeData`. But there are still same number of `item.user.activeData` with only two fields `user_id` and `last_save_time`. Am I missing anything?